# Import a new file format without using maya api commands

Tags: python, import, maya

Is it possible to use the `maya.cmds` instead of using any maya API to load/import in a file format in which it is not part of Maya file types?

I have tried googling but to no avail results other than the `fileDialog` command in Maya, otherwise it would means I will need to implement maya API (where I totally do not have any experiences with it)

I tried the following:

```
multipleFilters = "chan (*.chan)"
fileList = cmds.fileDialog2(fileMode=1, fileFilter=multipleFilters, dialogStyle=2)
if not fileList:
    # return or print something or bail out early

filename = fileList[0]
cmds.file(filename, i=True)
```

Instead I keep getting the following error:

```
# Error: Unrecognized file.
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 3, in <module>
# RuntimeError: Unrecognized file. #
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

`cmds.file` only works for files with translators that are registered via the API, either in Python or C++.

You can, however, easily write python (or even mel) scripts which read files off disk and create stuff in your scenes. You can use `cmds.fileDiialog2` to present a file dialog to the user to pick file off disk, but it will be up to you to read the file.

```
multipleFilters = "chan (*.chan)"
fileList = cmds.fileDialog2(fileMode=1, fileFilter=multipleFilters, dialogStyle=2)

with open (fileList[0], 'rt') as filehandle:
     for line in filehandle:
         print line # or do something useful with the data
```

Comment: Hi, I can see that it is able to read the file but is there any ways that I can make it to be imported into the scene? So far, I have only know the `cmds.file` method as a means of importing, not to mention that I do not have any file translators that are catered for `.chan` within my plugin directory

Comment: if you have a registered translator (and you've got it enabled) you can open it with `cmds.file`.  Otherwise you can just read a text file and do  script operations in the currently open scene based on what you've read. It's not 'importing' per se but it's a pretty common approach.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong. Does registered translator = plugins? If so, this would means that this operation may involves API? Sorry, I am getting a bit confused as I was being whirled in circles by the importing with API etc

Comment: Yes: you need to derive a class from MPXFileTranslator and implement the reader() method.  You might want to look at http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/mayasdk2012/en_us/index.html If you're having trouble getting started you might want to look at Adam Mechtley's book on Maya Python, which has an api section at the back although I don't recall if it does file translators

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me and I think your answer is totally what I had wanted to know as I was given the impression that I can import/open a file (not within Maya's list of file formats) through using `maya.cmds` I will try to look up on that book as well as sourcing for any file translators docs